# I have to create a mutable dictionary but i am getting an "Incompatible pointer types initializing" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mutable

I am trying to create a dictionary that will contain a key with a value 'Object_Info'.
I have the following code and get this error:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableDictionary *' with an expression of type 'NSDictionary *'
```

Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Object_Info : NSObject
{
    NSString *product;
    float cost;
    int qty;
}
@end


@implementation Object_Info

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]){
        product = @"";
        cost = 0.0;
        qty = 0;      
    }
    return self;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
          NSMutableDictionary *stock = @{ //ERROR IS HERE!!!!!
                                @"Lawn Chair" : [Object_Info new],
                                @"Beach Chair" : [Object_Info new],
                                @"Kitchen Chair" : [Object_Info new],
                                @"Futon" : [Object_Info new],
                                };

        for(NSString *key in [stock allKeys]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[stock objectForKey:key]);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're having is that you are trying to assign an NSDictionary to a NSMutableDictionary.

Try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *stock = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[stock setDictionary:@{
                                                @"Lawn Chair" : [Object_Info new],
                                                @"Beach Chair" : [Object_Info new],
                                                @"Kitchen Chair" : [Object_Info new],
                                                @"Futon" : [Object_Info new],
                                                }];
```

Comment: If this solved your problem can you mark it as the correct answer please